# Updating user input of radius instead of infinitely printing the same radius

Tags: python, user-input

I'm writing a simple program that takes in some user input and asks the user for a decimal that will be their radius. This is what i have so far:

```
import math

radius_string = "Radius" 
area_string = "Area"
volume_string = "Volume"

#takes in a radius and then calculates the surface area and the surface volume
first_radius = float(input("Input a decimal: "))
s_area = 4*math.pi*pow(first_radius,2)
s_volume = (4/3)*math.pi*pow(first_radius,3)

#aligns the title strings
print("{:<5}{:^10}{:>5}".format(radius_string,area_string,volume_string))

#formats the results of the radius area and volume to two decimal places
final_radius = ('{:.2f}'.format(first_radius))
final_area = ('{:.2f}'.format(s_area))
final_volume = ('{:.2f}'.format(s_volume))

#Trying to show user all the radiuses that they have inputed
while True:
     if final_radius and final_area and final_volume == type(float):
        final_radius = ('{:.2f}' .format(first_radius))
        final_area = ('{:.2f}' .format(s_area))
        final_volume = ('{:.2f}' .format(s_volume))
        continue
        first_radius = float(input("Input a decimal: "))

     print("{:<5}{:^10}{:>5}".format(final_radius,final_area,final_volume))
```

The problem is that it keeps infinitely printing the users radius and its respective surface area and volume. I put a while loop so it could print out only one radius with its surface area and volume, stop after that has happened to ask the new user for a new radius and then print out that radius. The idea i had was to print out every radius the user inputs and sort of storing them like in a table so the user can see the different radiuses that they put in.
Im pretty much a beginner, so there problably is a simple fix but any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: `final_radius and final_area and final_volume == type(float):` doesn't make sense because (a) that's not how you check if the type of something is `float`, and (b) that's not how multiple equality checks work in Python

Comment: To coax you to your solution: what's the only part of your program that loops? If you want the user to provide a radius _repeatedly_, why aren't you asking inside that loop?

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Stepping through your program and observing how each statement affects your variables and the flow of the program will be _extremely enlightening_

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you don't understand the `continue` statement.  That statement returns to the top of the loop for the next iteration.  You have no way to reach the `input` statement after that.
Simply delete the `continue`, and you'll see a distinctive change in your operation.

```
#Trying to show user all the radiuses that they have input
while True:
     if final_radius and final_area and final_volume == type(float):
        final_radius = ('{:.2f}' .format(first_radius))
        final_area = ('{:.2f}' .format(s_area))
        final_volume = ('{:.2f}' .format(s_volume))
        continue
        first_radius = float(input("Input a decimal: "))
```

There are other problems with your code; Stack Overflow postings should deal with a single issue, so I'll leave the others to your later debugging.  You seem to be trying to write the entire program before you test any of your code.  This gets you into the difficult situation of trying to find multiple bugs at once.